# Print with DocPrintJob

Tags: java

I am Brazilian, I don't speak very well English. Sorry...

My code:

```
PrintService[] printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
PrintService impressoraPadrao = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
HashDocAttributeSet hashDocAttributeSet = new HashDocAttributeSet();

FileInputStream stream;
try {
    stream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Rodrigo\\Desktop\\Trab4_Luc\\SCRIPTS.txt"));
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(stream, docFlavor, hashDocAttributeSet);
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService printServico = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 300, 200, printService, impressoraPadrao, docFlavor, printRequestAttributeSet);
    if (printServico != null) {
        DocPrintJob docPrintJob = printServico.createPrintJob();

        try {
            docPrintJob.print(doc, printRequestAttributeSet);
        } catch (PrintException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

This code doesn't error, but doesn't print...

Direct printing in notepad works normal...

But if I send a picture print Normal

```
public void imprimir(String texto) {
    PrintService[] printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
    PrintService impressoraPadrao = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG;
    HashDocAttributeSet hashDocAttributeSet = new HashDocAttributeSet();

    try {
         FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Rodrigo\\Desktop\\Trab4_Luc\\teste.png");
         Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(stream, docFlavor, hashDocAttributeSet);
         PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
         PrintService printServico = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 300, 200, printService, impressoraPadrao, docFlavor, printRequestAttributeSet);
         if (printServico != null) {
         DocPrintJob docPrintJob = printServico.createPrintJob();
         try {
             docPrintJob.print(doc, printRequestAttributeSet);
         } catch (PrintException e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
         }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you know there's SO in Portuguese too. :-)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ (@Leo mentioned it already)

Comment: also, your code worked fine in my linux box.

Comment: Stackoverflow English is better than the Portuguese :-). I use Windows 8 and not working.  You tested this my code in Linux?